# PayPal sdk doesn't go in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

i have some problems with PayPal sdk  on iOS.I created my app at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps and got client id . i used paypal sample apps with my ID its working fine in mock and sandbox mode. when i am using this in my apps each time my apps moving in mock data  mode i am getting response from paypal server.

```
{
    client =     {
        environment = mock;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.2.1";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2014-08-27T10:18:57Z";
        id = "PAY-8UD377151U972354RKOQ3DTQ";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
```

.i am not anle to set sandbox mode which variable i need to use .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Set up payPalConfig
    _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = @"en";
    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"KicksCloset Shoes, Inc.";
    _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];
    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];
    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];
    // use default environment, should be Production in real life
     self.environment = @"sandbox";

    NSLog(@"PayPal iOS SDK version: %@", [PayPalMobile libraryVersion]);


}
```

this is my pay action

```
{   
    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:amountforserver];
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = creditsforserver;
   // payment.items = items;  // if not including multiple items, then leave payment.items as nil
  //  payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails; // if not including payment details, then leave payment.paymentDetails as nil

    if (!payment.processable) {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.
    }

    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
    self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                     delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your action method have issue .

just pass the environment 
{

```
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:amountforserver];
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = creditsforserver;
   // payment.items = items;  // if not including multiple items, then leave payment.items as nil
  //  payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails; // if not including payment details, then leave payment.paymentDetails as nil

    if (!payment.processable) {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.
    }
    self.environment = kPayPalEnvironment;

        PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                    configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                         delegate:self];

        [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}
and just use this 
code in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:self.environment];
}
```

Comment: let me know if any issue

Answer (score 2):

change your paypal environment to PayPalEnvironmentSandbox

this is for sandbox mode

```
self.environment = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
```

if you want go with live mode..

```
  self.environment = PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
```

check your PayPalMobile.h file

/// This environment MUST be used for App Store submissions.

```
extern NSString *const PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
```

/// Sandbox: Uses the PayPal sandbox for transactions. Useful for development.

```
extern NSString *const PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
```

/// NoNetwork: Mock mode. Does not submit transactions to PayPal. Fakes successful responses. Useful for unit tests.

```
extern NSString *const PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork;
```

Comment: environment = kPayPalEnvironment;i have used this but still not getting in sandbox mode.

Comment: what is kPayPalEnvironment?where you initialize this?